# SSL on Tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

I've been trying all day to set Tomcat 6.0 up for SSL. I know it shouldn't be that hard. I've followed the Tomcat documentation in creating my own Certificate, configuring the connectors in the server.xml file.

When I go to https://localhost:8443, (8443 is the port I defined in the connector) my certificate does not render on the screen, and my browser tells me that it was unable to make a secure connection to the server and that my client may not have the certificate.

My question is, why isn't my certificate rendering for the user to say "Trust" or "Not"?

Comment: Did your buy your certificate?

Comment: I did not buy it. I created it myself using keytool...

Comment: Just FYI, here is what my connector looks like in server.xml

Comment: <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
      keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="somepassword"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />

Comment: And where is your keystore file stored? Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: My keyfile is stored in my UserDirectoy, Windows.

C:\Users\han.cg.NA\.keystore

Answer (score 1):

There's a full documentation on [SSL Howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) for Tomcat 6. I don't know how far you've gone to setting up your SSL for me to help you.

Make sure that in `server.xml` in `APACHE_HOME/conf` has both `Connector` for port 8080 and 8443 enabled.

Comment: Check. In my case it the default port is 8001, and my ssl port is 8443.

Comment: And how does your connector for port `8001` look like?

Comment: <Connector port="8001" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: It's correct, I don't see what the problem is...what does the log say? `APACHE_HOME/logs/`

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to have a `tcnative-1.dll` file in `apache-tomcat-6.xxx\bin\` folder?

If so, it will not work with your current `<Connector/>` configuration. Remove the file or rename the extension and restart the tomcat server again.

This is stated in "Edit the Tomcat Configuration File" section of http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out.

The issue was regarding to my protocol variable in my Connector:

This is what I had: protocol="HTTP/1.1"

Now I have this: protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"

The only issue now is that chrome or IE won't run the site as HTTPS because i signed the certificate myself and am not a CA.

Comment: you can import your self-signed certificate into the browser and mark it as a trusted certificate.  In Chrome: Preferences > Under the Hood > Security > Manage Certificates  In IE see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179380.  Search Google for more details or other browsers.

Comment: When I try to import my certificate, I am asked to browse for the certificate file. I do not know where this is.

The only file I know of is my .keystore file in my profile.

Comment: You can export your certificate from your keystore file (.keystore).  Here's an example: `keytool -storepass my-keystore-password -alias myalias -exportcert -file outfilename.cer`.  You can add a `-rfc` parameter to export the certificate as text (base-64 encoded).  See the keytool docs for more information: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html